# Filter Array of Objects by specific user and specific property

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, sorting

I have an object like this

```
users = [{persona: 1, userId: 4, date: 2021-05-14},
{persona: 2, userId: 4, date: 2021-05-12},
{persona: 3, userId: 4, date: 2021-05-14},
{persona: 2, userId: 4, date: 2021-05-13},
{persona: 1, userId: 3, date: 2021-05-18},
{persona: 1, userId: 3, date: 2021-05-17}]
```

and I would like to filter the array of objects to have only 1 result per userId and persona sorted by latest dateTime. So the array can have multiple of the same userIds(with different personas) and multple of the same personas(different userIds), just not the same userId and persona match. If there are matching userIds and personas I would like to only keep the latest one according to Date.
Thank you in advance for you help.
Below is an example of how I would like the users array above to be filtered

```
users = [{persona: 1, userId: 4, date: 2021-05-14},
{persona: 3, userId: 4, date: 2021-05-14},
{persona: 2, userId: 4, date: 2021-05-13},
{persona: 1, userId: 3, date: 2021-05-18}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort then select distinct using object keys

```
let distinct = {};
users = users
    .sort((a, b) => a.date > b.date ? -1 : 1)
    .forEach(p => {
        let key = p.persona.toString() + p.userId.toString();
        distinct[key] = p;
    });
let distinctUsers = Object.keys(distinct).map(k => distinct[k])
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner answer would be to use the following:

```
users = users
.sort((a, b) => a.date > b.date ? -1 : 1)
.filter((v,i,a)=>a.findIndex(t =>(t.persona === v.persona && t.userId===v.userId))===i);
```

Here the array is first sorted and then duplicates based on combination of *persona* and *userId* are filtered out.